# convert decimal to HH.MM format in SQl Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to convert decimal to `HH.MM` format in SQl Server. Example:- 06.85 will be converted to 07.25, 06.60 will be converted to 7.00

Comment: Why would the first example have a leading zero and the second not? Typo I'm guessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select floor(06.85) + cast(((06.85 - floor(06.85))*100) as int) / 60 + cast((cast((06.85 - floor(06.85)) * 100 as int) % 60) as float) / 100

 select floor(06.60) + cast(((06.60 - floor(06.60))*100) as int) / 60 + cast((cast((06.60 - floor(06.60)) * 100 as int) % 60) as float) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN DecimalValue - FLOOR(DecimalValue) >= 0.6 THEN DecimalValue + 1 - 0.6
            ELSE DecimalValue 
        END AS HHMMFormat
    FROM
        MyTable
```

Obviously the `+ 1 - 0.6` could be replaced by `+ 0.4` but I thought that `+ 1 - 0.6` more clearly showed the reason for the addition.